# Drupal 7: recognize returning users using email

Tags: forms, drupal

I've searched online trying to find an answer but unable to do so decided to post my question here. I have to implement subscription-like service on our website, here is the flow:
1. New user wants to download file
       a. User is provided a pop-up/decision page for new/returning user
       b. User selects new user
       c. Direct user to a web form
       d. Fill out and submit form (If user select Subscribe checkbox we should send email with notifications when new file is added - in our case it means that we added a new page/node)
       e. On the Thank You page user is provided a link to download the file
2. Returning user
       a. On the pop-up/decision page user asked to enter email
       b. Verify that email is logged in the database and direct user to a page with a link to download file or initiate download. (Email is logged at the first time user submits the form)

This mechanism should allow us to track who downloads the file and at the same time do not overload the user to fill out the same form every time.

Please, advice me how I can achieve this flow.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two options i can think of - one is using Drupal's users system.
You can provide a link that actually registers the user to the system - he'll need to provide also a password. The registered users will get a special role that will allow them to download the page.

The second option is to use Drupal webform + webform_validation - check out: http://drupal.org/project/webform_validation

Comment: We are definitely don't want to create a user accounts. This is ultimately the user flow we want to achieve: http://www.millennialmedia.com/mobile-intelligence/smart-report/. Click on Download PDF.

Comment: In that case use - webform module. you can add to the submission form a rule that you can then validate. (check if the email record is already in the system).